# Increasing specificity in Caret package in R

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am trying to use logistic regression with caret. Data frame is  "Default" in "ISLR2" package.
I am geting low specificity (27%), due to default probability threshold of 0.5.
What is the way to change this default probability threshlod, say to 0.2 or 0.7.
The code used is as below:

```
set.seed(7702)
# test & train partition
index <- sample(1:nrow(Default), 0.80*nrow(Default))
train_default <- Default[index, ]
test_default <- Default[-index, ]

# Creating controling parameters
controlValues <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                              number = 10,
                              savePredictions = "all",
                              classProbs = TRUE)
# building the model
model_default <- train(default ~ income + balance,
                       data = train_default,
                       method = "glm",
                       family = binomial,
                       trControl = controlValues)

# Model  prediction & confusion Matrix
model_pred <- predict(model_default, 
                      newdata = test_default)
confusionMatrix(model_pred, test_default$default)
```

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
      Reference
```

Prediction   No  Yes
No  1937   41
Yes    7   15

```
           Accuracy : 0.976           
             95% CI : (0.9683, 0.9823)
No Information Rate : 0.972           
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.1543          
                                      
              Kappa : 0.3747
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.906e-06

```
        Sensitivity : 0.9964          
        Specificity : 0.2679
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `predict` function you need to specify de `type='prob'` parameter. This allows you to get all the probabilities and choose the threshold of your preference.

```
model_pred <- predict(model_default, newdata = test_default, type = "prob")
```

Then, you can manually make a classification. For example:

```
model_pred_class <- ifelse(model_pred < 0.2, "No", "Yes")
```